# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp GET gets cancelled on screen rotate?

Tags: android, android-async-http, loopj

I execute the following code that does not execute if I rotate the screen:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get(absoluteUrl, params, responseHandler);
```

It surprised me that the network request was cancelled because if I used a custom asynctask to make a network call using, say, URLConnection it would still run even after the activity was destroyed.  Am I to understand that loopj's AndroidAsyncHttp cancels the network request when the activity is destroyed?  How can I prevent this?

Comment: Hey did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I need more information to help you. What I can tell you is that by default 
android destroys and recreates an activity on rotation.

If you specify the following in your android manifest:

```
      <activity
        android:name=".exampleActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
    </activity>
```

The activity wont be destroyed but onConfigurationChanged will be called instead.

Hoped this helped 8=)